# Extract values from a json object using a function node

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I have a problem and knowing how to ask the correct question is key!  I was looking around and found someone asking the same question in a different way, unfortunately the answer was not complete. So I am going to ask it here using my flows and situation.

I  am trying  to extract values from an json object using a function node, tried many ways and nothing seems to work for me. I am trying to extract 7 values to create 7 different messages with 7 different Topics so they can be published via 7 different MQTT nodes.
This is the complete message object:

`

```
2022-11-11, 1:59:04 p.m.node: 3ec81adb55be266d
v3/rak-wis-blocks@ttn/devices/rak4631-sensor1/up : msg : Object
object
topic: "v3/rak-wis-blocks@ttn/devices/rak4631-sensor1/up"
payload: object
Vbat_Per: 110
Vbat: 4269
Fixed: 1
TemperatureAM: 11.85
HumidityAM: 99.99
TempInside: 12.42
Pressure: 995.44
qos: 0
retain: false
_msgid: "85957ff31d82e49b"
```

`

I found an example that used a Function node, with the below code, and it spits out 7 separate messages with the variables I want.  I just don't know how to take each new message and modify its properties with new and different Topic values.
Example: topic: sensor/Vbat_per,  topic: sensor/Vbat,  topic: sensor/Fixed, etc.

`

```
var keys = Object.keys(msg.payload);

var msgs = keys.map(function(key) {
    return { topic: key, payload: msg.payload[key] };
});
return [msgs];
```

`

This is the output from the Function node with the above code:
`

```
2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
Vbat_Per : msg.payload : number
75

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
Vbat : msg.payload : number
4034

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
Fixed : msg.payload : number
1

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
TemperatureAM : msg.payload : number
12.32

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
HumidityAM : msg.payload : number
99.99

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
TempInside : msg.payload : number
12.49

2022-11-11, 3:09:04 p.m.node: 9bc14535de62758e
Pressure : msg.payload : number
994.3
```

`

To me it looks like there are 7 new messages with only a payload and no Topic.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Set the debug node to show the whole message. By default it only shows the `msg.payload`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I did that and discovered what I was missing. I was able to resolve my issue by using a switch Node with 7 outputs keying on the Topic for each of the new messages.  Then from there in to 7 separate Change nodes to modify the Topic to what I needed.  It may be a brute force method but it does work.